# How Can I display my Admob banner ads in the middle of the screen?

Tags: android, admob

Below is my xml file. This admob is showing bottom of the page. But I need to show the admob ads middle of the screen. What can be done to solve the problem?

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="test.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/include_playerstrip">


        <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
            android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp"
            android:paddingTop="4dp"
            android:textColor="#fff" />

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/include_playerstrip"
        layout="@layout/play_util" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

I have attached one screenshot of the ads where I need to show middle of the screen.

Comment: Have you tried placing android:layout_centerInParent="true" within the AdView widget?

Comment: @AdamGardner yes I tried it but it is not working for me

Comment: Why are you putting ads in the middle of the screen in the first place? That's just about the worst place you could place them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changed your AdView widget to

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

This for me allowed the Ad to be centered on the screen horizontally and vertically.